# Add attributes directly within an append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you add attributes to an element within an append, something like this:

```
var video = $("<video>").append("<source>", {
  src: 'https://www.youtube.com/', 
  width: 100, 
  height: 200
});
```

I'm asking because I think I have seen something like this before, but can't quite remember how it was written. I know you can do this with jQuery and attr(), but I'm looking for a way without using attr() or similar methods.

I think it was written with jQuery, but might have been something like underscorejs aswell, I'm not sure. Anyone know?

Comment: Should you not wrap `<source>` inside `$()`? `.append` expects a `htmlString` or `DOM node`

Comment: Why are you looking to do it without `.attr()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but missing the jQuery wrapper when creating the child element:

```
var video = $("<video />").append($("<source />", {
  src: 'https://www.youtube.com/', 
  width: 100, 
  height: 200
}));
```

Comment: I'd just close `<video/>` to make it compatible for most brows*IE*rs

Answer (score 0):

No but what you can is:

```
var video = $("<video />");
$("<source />", {
  src: 'https://www.youtube.com/', 
  width: 100, 
  height: 200,
  appendTo : video
});
```

Comment: You can. He is missing `$('<source>').attr({})` inside `.append`

Comment: @Rajesh that's not true. You don't need any `attr` (if you know jQuery). Utkanos solution is also good BTW.

Comment: Yes i know that. I had already commented same thing on question.